# Span with red background not visible?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a a list of elements, I am trying to display them, if one of the element is clicked, the font weigh changes to bold, and a decoration ( underline ) is added, the uderline thickness is 3px, so to do that I added a span in my link element, I set my link to relative and the span to absolute, and added my other stylings, like that : ( Please go to the header options )

```
<div class="header__top-bar">
            <div class="header__logo-icons">
                <img class="header__logo" src="assets/images/cdiscountvoyage-trimmy.png" alt="logo">
                <div class="header__icons-container">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="assets/images/instagram.png" alt="facebook">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="assets/images/pinterest.png" alt="facebook">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header__options">
                <a href="#">
                    <span style="display: inline-block;">Séjour</span>
                    <span style=" position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px; height: 3px; width: 100%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                        <span style="display: inline-block;">Séjour</span>
                        <span style=" position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px; height: 3px; width: 100%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span>
                </a>

                <a href="#">
                        <span style="display: inline-block;">Séjour</span>
                        <span style=" position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px; height: 3px; width: 100%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the styling ( what is needed I think ) :

```
.header__options {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header__options a {

    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;

    font-size: 14px;

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header__options a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Now, I am not implemting the js code to see the click event, I am not just seeing the underline ffect I added, so here is what I have :

[image]

But when I inspect my element, I see it is there, but not visible, it is like it has a negative z-index or whatever, the header background is hiding it, but I am not sure.

[image]

And this is the mockup, what I am trying to have :

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran this code, removing `x-overflow: scroll;` seemed to work, and I could see the underlines.

Also, consider using pseudo elements (`::after`, `::before`) for these kinds of things. They will make your life easier and the code cleaner.

Also, if you aren't sure why you can't see an element, try moving it around. Change the z-index. Change it's `position` and `display` property. These are just easy ways to debug these kinds of errors.

Comment: Yes, it is normal, but I have to add the scrolling ?? I addded the after and before elements to my code but did not work, they did not even show up so I moved to this solution, .

Comment: And your answer looks like a comment more like an answer, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add **padding-bottom** to **.header__options** class. After this i think you can see the under lines.

```css
.header__options {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: darkblue;
    padding-bottom: 10px; /* added pading bottom to get space in bottom */
}

.header__options a {

    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header__options a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header__options">
    <a href="#">
        <span style="display: inline-block;">Séjour</span>
        <span style=" position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px; height: 3px; width: 100%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <span style="display: inline-block;">Séjour</span>
        <span style=" position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px; height: 3px; width: 100%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <span style="display: inline-block;">Séjour</span>
        <span style=" position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px; height: 3px; width: 100%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it a solution, but it will add height to my element you see, if I do so, I won't respect some thing I have in the mockups..

Answer (score 0):

Span tag is an inline element. You can't fix height and width for this. It always used to wrap the content with content's height and width.
So what you can do here is, add border-bottom style to your a tag. And remove your empty span.
border-bottom: 3px solid red;

Hope this will help you.